# bootstrap/autoload.php - Failed to open stream: permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5

I'm working with a website running on laravel. The site works fine on my local through Homestead, no problems.

Recently, I pushed the git repo up to a server that never had this site running on it before. I set everything up right (had some nginx config issues for a while, but got those all sorted out). Nginx has the public folder set as the site root, so it hits the proper index page when you load the page.

What I'm getting is a 500 error. My error logs reveal the following is the reason:

```
site_root/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php - Failed to open stream: permission denied

in

site_root/public/index.php on line 22
```

I can confirm that the bootstrap folder and the autoload.php file are both accessible by the web user, and have permissions that should allow access.

I've read a few cases online of people solving this issue with a 'composer install'. I tried updating composer, doing an install, and dumping its cache. I also tried removing the vendor folder (which had been a part of the git repo), and running composer install to regenerate it. None of these have worked. Happy to supply any info that will help. This is Laravel 5.2 running on Ubuntu Server 14.04 with nginx, all on an AWS box.

Comment: permission denied means that your `autoload.php` file does not has the `read/write` permissions. Better to give read/write permissions individually, and then try it.

Comment: I have tried giving autoload.php 777 permissions (which I reverted, just did it as a test), and also ensured that the owner (ubuntu) was a part of the group www-data, the same group that the nginx user www-data runs under. All my other web roots on the same box that also run under nginx have all their files owned by ubuntu:ubuntu, and it never causes issues, but I added it to the www-data group just in case. Still no luck, permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. This was actually an issue with site-wide permissions. They were set to 770 instead of 775. I suspect that I can and should restrict them more. For now, I'm just happy to have it loading again.

Moral of the story is to check your permissions site-wide, not necessarily just on the file which gives you the fatal error. You may continue to get the same fatal error, despite permissions being wide-open on the mentioned file. If so, look for permissions issues elsewhere.